# Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, string, codeigniter, object

here is my code :

```
class Mymodel extends CI_Model {

public function getinstitution()
    {
    $course = "programming";
    $location = "jakarta";
    $price = "price2";

    $data = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM coursesplace WHERE 1=1');

    if($course)     $data .= "AND course=\"$course\" ";
    if($location)   $data .= "AND location=\"$location\" ";
    if($price)      $data .= "AND price=\"$price\"";

    return $data->result_array();
    }
}
```

I want to filter computer course places based on three variables (course, location and price), with string data type. I have "programming", "jakarta", and "price2" for example.

But, then I have this error :

**A PHP Error was encountered**

**Severity: 4096**

**Message: Object of class CI_DB_mysqli_result could not be converted to string**

**Filename: models/mymodel.php**

**Line Number: 14**

---> Line 14 is :

```
if($course)     $data .= "AND course=\"$course\" ";
```

AND other error :

**A PHP Error was encountered**

**Severity: Error**

**Message: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object**

**Filename: models/mymodel.php**

**Line Number: 18**

---> Line 18 is :

```
return $data->result_array();
```

What should I do? Thanks for the answer !

Comment: What do you mean by 1=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just simply get rid of quotes as

```
$data = 'SELECT * FROM coursesplace WHERE 1=1';

if ($course)
    $data .= " AND course='$course' ";
if ($location)
    $data .= " AND location='$location' ";
if ($price)
    $data .= " AND price='$price'";

$result = $this->db->query($data);
return $result->result_array();
```

Active Records..

```
public function getinstitution() {
    $course = "programming";
    $location = "jakarta";
    $price = "price2";

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('coursesplace');
    $this->db->where('1 = 1');
    if ($course != '') {
        $this->db->where('course', $course);
    }
    if ($location != '') {
        $this->db->where('location', $location);
    }
    if ($price != '') {
        $this->db->where('price', $price);
    }
    $data = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$data is an object you cant concatinate string to object.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM coursesplace WHERE 1=1"


    if(isset($course))     $query .= " AND course=\"$course\" ";
    if(isset($location))   $query .= " AND location=\"$location\" ";
    if(isset($price))      $query .= " AND price=\"$price\" ";

 $data = $this->db->query($query);
```

This will help.
i have taken a variable $query and assign string to it
according to the conditions string is concatenated. 
And at the end the final query is give to $this->db->query

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're running the query, then trying to ammend the query afterwards.

You should add "SELECT * FROM coursesplace WHERE 1=1" to the $data string, like this;

```
$data = 'SELECT * FROM coursesplace WHERE 1=1';
// Then ammend the $data
if($course)     $data .= "AND course=\"$course\" ";
if($location)   $data .= "AND location=\"$location\" ";
if($price)      $data .= "AND price=\"$price\"";

// Now run the query
$query = $this->db->query($data);

return $query->result_array();
```